# Custom Part not rendering in Widget in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/549374

I'm using Orchard 1.8, and I've built a part that I've attached to a widget. It's a basic part but I'm having issues rendering the template. Here's my code:

**MODEL**

```
public class AppsWidgetRecord : ContentPartRecord {        
}

public class AppsWidgetPart : ContentPart<AppsWidgetRecord> {    
}
```

**DRIVER**

```
public class AppsWidgetDriver : ContentPartDriver<AppsWidgetPart>
{
    protected override DriverResult Display(AppsWidgetPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_AppsWidget",
            () => shapeHelper.Partial(
                TemplateName: "Parts/AppsWidget"
        ));
    }
}
```

***I have an AppsWidget.cshtml under View/Parts***

**MIGRATION**

```
        #region Define Apps Widget

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            typeof(AppsWidgetPart).Name, cfg => cfg.Attachable());

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("AppsWidget", cfg => cfg
            .WithPart("WidgetPart")
            .WithPart(typeof(AppsWidgetPart).Name)
            .WithPart("CommonPart")
            .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));

        #endregion

        #region Create Apps Widget

        var appsWidget = _widgetsService.CreateWidget(homepageLayer.Id, "AppsWidget", "Apps", "5", "AfterContent");
        appsWidget.RenderTitle = true;
        appsWidget.Name = "apps";
        _contentManager.Publish(appsWidget.ContentItem);

        #endregion
```

**PLACEMENT**

```
<Place Parts_AppsWidget="AfterContent:5" />
```

The widget renders fine, the template of the part however, does not render at all. When I shape trace, the appswidgetpart is nowhere to be seen under the widget, but when I check the model it is there.

[image]

I've also debugged and attached to the display function within the driver, and no issues come about. I don't see any errors in the logs as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be missing a handler. Also, why do you have a record class if it's going to be empty?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are displaying the shape properly in the driver. I usually do it like this.

```
protected override DriverResult Display(AppsWidgetPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return ContentShape(
        "Parts_AppsWidget",
        () => shapeHelper.Parts_AppsWidget(ContentItem: part.ContentItem));
}
```